# Unclear step in Eisenbud's proof of a variant of Hauptidealsatz

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-verification

I need help in understanding the proof of the following

> **Theorem 10.1**. If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime of a Noetherian ring $R$ minimal subject to containing $x \in R$, then its height is at most one.

In the context of $\mathfrak{q}$ being another prime, strictly contained in $\mathfrak{p}$, the author replaces $R$ with $R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, concluding by minimality that $R/(x)$ is Artinian.

Now, I believe this is not true: take for instance $R = k[[t]]$, $\mathfrak{p} = (t)$ and $x = 0$. Then $R_{\mathfrak{p}} = R$ so $R/(x)$ is isomorphic to $R$ which is not Artinian.

I can't find my mistake, or the way to use the theorem cited in the proof given, namely

> **Theorem 2.14**. $R$ is Noetherian with all primes maximal iff it is of finite length iff it is Artinian, in which case it has finitely many primes.

to derive that $R/(x)$ is Artinian. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In THM 10.1, $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal among primes containing $x$.  In your example, this is not the case.

Using that $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal among primes containing $x$, the maximal ideal of $R_{\mathfrak{p}}/(x)R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is also minimal, so $R_{\mathfrak{p}}/(x)R_{\mathfrak{p}}$ must be Artinian.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why it occurred to me that $(0)$ just doesn't qualify as "minimal".:(

Comment: You're welcome.  Only 500 pages of Eisenbud left!